# How to interrupt epoll_pwait with an appropriate signal?

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interrupting epoll_wait with a non-IO event, no signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244466/interrupting-epoll-wait-with-a-non-io-event-no-signals)

I have a thread that is currently using epoll_wait to flag the arrival of data on some sockets.  The timeout parameter is currently set to zero.

However, the thread also does other tasks.  What I want to do is change this so that if there is no work to be done then make it an indefinite or long time out.  This will dramatically reduce wasted CPU cycles spinning when there is no actual work to do.

The whole thing is driven mostly by the arrival of a message on a thread safe lock free queue.

So, what I think should happen is I should wake up the thread from it's long timeout using epoll_pwait.

However, I'm unsure what signal to send it and how this is done.  I'm not familiar with Linux signals.

The following is similar to what I currently have. Dramatically shorted to show the concept. If you spot a bug, don't bother pointing it out, this is just an illustration that I've typed in here to help you understand what I'm wanting to achieve.

```
// Called from another thread...
void add_message_to_queue(struct message_t* msg)
{
    add_msg(msg);
    raise( ? );  // wake the state machine?
}


// different thread to the above.
main_thread()
{
    struct message_t msg;
    while (msg = get_message_from_queue())
      process_message(msg);

    timeout = work_available ? 0 : -1;

    nfds = epoll_pwait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, timeout);
    for (i = 0; i < nfds; ++i)
    {
        if ((events[i].events & EPOLLIN) == EPOLLIN)
        {
           /// do stuff
        }
    }

    run_state_machines();
}
```

So I guess my question is really, is this the right way of going about it? and if so, what signal do I send and do I need to define a signal handler or can I use the signal disposition "ignore" and still be woken?

Comment: @rob mayoff thanks that other answer which I didn't see before was very helpful.  Happy to close this as a duplicate

Comment: @MattH: signals don't work well in threaded processes because asynchronous signals (ones delivered by `kill()`) can go to any thread.

Comment: As mentioned here http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-12.html : "If a signal occurs, the call will return with errno set to EINTR.".

Comment: The "duplicate" explicitly states "no signals". While THIS question asked how to do it with a signal. How can that be a duplicate?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of signals, consider using a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).  Create a pipe and add the file descriptor for the read end of the pipe to the epoll.  When you want to wake the epoll_wait call, just write 1 character to the write end of the pipe.

```
int read_pipe;
int write_pipe;
void InitPipe()
{
    int pipefds[2] = {};
    epoll_event ev = {};
    pipe(pipefds, 0);
    read_pipe = pipefds[0];
    write_pipe = pipefds[1];

    // make read-end non-blocking
    int flags = fcntl(read_pipe, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(write_pipe, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);

    // add the read end to the epoll
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = read_pipe;
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, read_pipe, &ev);

}

void add_message_to_queue(struct message_t* msg)
{
    char ch = 'x';
    add_msg(msg);
    write(write_pipe, &ch, 1);
}

main_thread()
{
    struct message_t msg;
    while (msg = get_message_from_queue())
      process_message(msg);

    timeout = work_available ? 0 : -1;

    nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, timeout);

    for (i = 0; i < nfds; ++i)
    {
        if (events[i].data.fd == read_pipe)
        {

            // read all bytes from read end of pipe
            char ch;
            int result = 1;
            while (result > 0)
            {
                result = read(epoll_read, &ch, 1);
            }
        }

        if ((events[i].events & EPOLLIN) == EPOLLIN)
        {
           /// do stuff
        }
    }

    run_state_machines();
}
```

Comment: I'm liking the eventfd thing on the dupe post... Linux only, but it's the same concept.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used an eventfd in the end which is an identical concept.  However, I'll accept your answer as it's the only answer provided here and works.

Comment: I think it is actually not correct, as the "self-pipe trick" was mainly used when the selectp and epoll_pwait didn't exist. More info there : http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-12.html

Comment: How do you call ```epoll_pwait``` function with 4 arguments (instead of 5)? Is it a mistake?

Comment: @isnullxbh - lol.  That typo has probably been there for years.

Comment: This is not an answer to question asked though... I need some simular info and then it is not nice to find an "answer" that doesn't contain the requested information of the question :/.

Comment: @CarloWood - I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: @CarloWood - the answer is don't use signals.  Use an eventfd or a pipe to wake up epoll_wait out of it's slumber

Comment: @selbie The question reads "How to interrupt epoll_pwait with an appropriate signal?". The answer involves setting an event handler with sigaction that set a global flag, blocking signals right before handling that flag and then entering epoll_pwait with a mask that unblocks that signal again; and the use of pthread_kill to send the actual signal to the thread running epoll_pwait. Saying "don't use signals" is not an answer to the actual question (I'm not arguing which is better/faster in practise).

Comment: @CarloWood - If you feel you have a **better solution**, then post it as an answer to the OP's question. I may even upvote it myself. But just whining about the accepted answer to someone else's question because it doesn't fit your particular scenario and ideals - well that's just petty.  I don't always give answers people want, instead I give them answers I feel they need. If people disagree, they can downvote, provide an alternate solution, or engage with me in a technical discussion. Sometimes, my best learnings on SO have originated from wrong answers.

Comment: Also, I never said **"don't use signals"**.  I said, "**consider**".   Big difference.

Comment: I didn't have a solution when I posted my comment - then I was looking for the answer to the OP's question :p. Now I do, but since this is a 7 year old question that is marked as a duplicate of a question that doesn't even cover it, it seems better to create a new question first.